# calling asp.net mvc 5 web api in asp.net core, FromBody always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I call the asp.net mvc 5 web api in Asp.net Core the input parameter FromBody always is null

asp.net Mvc 6 web api

```
public void Post([FromBody]string id)
{

}
```

calling web api in asp.net core

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
      string stringData = JsonConvert.
      SerializeObject("test");
      var contentData = new StringContent(stringData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
      HttpResponseMessage response1 = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:49741/api/values/", contentData).Result;      
  }
```

Comment: You should probably serialize `new { id = "test" }` instead of just a string.

Comment: i changed JsonConvert.SerializeObject("test");
 to  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { id = "test" });
but not work

Comment: What do you mean by `not work`?

Comment: If you remove `FromBody` What is the value of `if` if you post to `http://localhost:49741/api/values/?id=test`?

Comment: Have you been able to call the API successfully from somewhere else (e.g. Postman)?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand the problem.

Comment: If you really want to receive a string try using `text/plain` as the content type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Crowcoder said. You should register `MediaTypeFormatter`. Here simple arctile [how do](https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/c-supporting-textplain-in-an-mvc-4-rc-web-api-application/) that provides to do what you want.

But simpler is choose another way to work with incoming data. As `application/json`. Create simple Dto class like:

```
public class TestDataDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

And change argument type of your Post method:

```
// POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]TestDataDto value)
{

}
```

Then code of your core client should be like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var someData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Id = "test" });
        var content = new StringContent(someData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var result = httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:55878/api/values", content).Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("All is fine");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Something was wrong. HttpStatus: {result.StatusCode}");
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: +1 but `HttpClient` should be re-used, not newed up for every request. It is OK to leave that undisposed for the life of the application.